# How can I run a newman command from java

Tags: java

The code I am using to try run my newman command from Java is :

```
Process processObject = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("newman run 'C:/Dev/config/service-tests/postmanCollections/test.json' -r  json,html");
```

When this is executed I get the following error:

```
Cannot run program "newman": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

is there an alternative way to run this?

Comment: It seems the "newman" command isn't found, are you running Java from the same command line that you're using for manual runs of "newman"? Did you try supplying the full path or calling a batch file that executes "newman"?

Comment: the error message contains a single quote before `newman`, where does that come from?

Comment: @f1sh the single quote was a typo. The actual error has no quote

Comment: I am using the same command line that I run for my manual newman tests. I have not tried to specify full path. I will try now @Thomas

Comment: @Thomas using full path did not work

Comment: Can you post the command you're successfully executing manually?

Comment: @Thomas "newman run 'C:/Dev/config/service-tests/postmanCollections/test.json' -r  json,html"

Answer (score 0):

We need to add cmd.exe for newman if you are running from windows machine i.e.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c newman run 'C:\\Dev\\config\\service-tests\\postmanCollections\\test.json' -r  json,html");
```